# Background detection in a single image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection, background-subtraction

I am writing a code in which I require subtraction of the background part of a **single image**. All the methods demonstrated online are for video files. Is there any way of subtracting the background when we have only a single image available? For example consider this image:

[image: This figure is prepared from the Stanford house number dataset]

My question is, is there any way of segregating the numbers from there background so that we can detect them quite easily?
The Stanford house number dataset is available [here](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/)

Answer (score 1):

You need numbers segmentation, not background. After you segmented numbers, just invert mask. Many neural networks can be trained for this task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you post some links describing number segmentation techniques?

Comment: I know no trained networks for it, but you can train your own. You can use fcn-8 architecture for instance: https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/fcn8s_tensorflow or YOLO based https://github.com/ArtyZe/yolo_segmentation there a lot of architectures you can use. Google instance segmentation or semantic segmentation, But you'll of cause need to annotate your dataset.